# Is there a way of adding a scrollbar horizontally and vertically to a Text Input in Kivy?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am new to Kivy and Pyhton and I want to put a scrollbar horizontally and vertically to a Text Input. I don’t want to use a ScrollView, because I am making a desktop app and it is not that intuitive as the user has to click and drag up and down or sidewards in the Text Input". I also found on the internet how to make a draggable scrollbar using a slider (https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/A-draggable-scrollbar-using-a-slider), but I have’t been able to add it to the Text Input. Could anyone help me please?

Comment: The `ScrollView` will provide scrollbars. See the [documenttion](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html#kivy.uix.scrollview.ScrollView.scroll_type).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't know how I didn't see that